# Count found rows on LIMIT affected queries using JDBI

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I'm using JDBI and I have `allowMultiQueries` set to true for my JDBC connection.

For the good old pagination issue, I'd like to get the number of affected rows if no `LIMIT` would have been set.

I've tried the following:

- do a `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 0,100; SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as myCount` but I get always 1. This is not a problem with the MySQL server nor the statistics being obsolete: I can run the query on MySQL Workbench and the results are correct
- use the same JDBI `handle`for both queries (the main query and the count query afterwards) without closing it. It will return 1 again

If I do it in pure JDBC I can iterate through the `ResultSet` but this is not an option, since I rely heavily on JDBI

**Note** I'd like to stay away from the use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` debate. I need to use it in some cases, only when suitable

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know JDBI, but JDBC can use `Statement.getMoreResults()` to get the next `ResultSet`...
try looking for something like that.

Comment: Thanks @UsagiMiyamoto, but I cannot get rid of `jdbi` since I want the mapping, parameter binding etc, and it's the base of all database access library that I'm using

Comment: I meant try looking for something like that in JDBI...

Comment: I've read it all and there's nothing related to multiple resultsets. You can send several queries with prepareBatch and createBatch, but not getting multiple resultsets AFAIK

Comment: Another option to get JDBC connection from JDBI, and use plain JDBC for getting values. Or even combine the two: get data with JDBI, with your fisrt query, and then get the number by executing a JDBC query...